# CustomerSession -How is the getNoReferer() method assigned value?

Tags: customer, session

Class **\Magento\Customer\Model\Url** - Line 122 
I can't find the place that system sets value for **getNoReferer**() method. 
Please show me how the system sets its value. 
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: try to search with keywords like `setNoReferer` or `setData('no_referer')`

Comment: Hi @Jimmy
I think so, but the result is "not found"